# How to get elements from an array that do not have certain letter, just using the for loop?

Tags: javascript

I need to get the elements from an array that do not have the letter `'l'` in them and push it to another array, just using the `for` loop. For this project no special methods are allowed. I can only use the `push()` and `toLowerCase()` methods.

The result I get is a list of all the names repeated multiple times.

```js
var list =['sage', 'carolina', 'everly', 'carlos', 'frankie'];
var list1 =[];

for(let i in list){
  for(let j in list[i]){
//Get name without the 'l'
    if(list[i][j].toLowerCase() !== 'l'){
      list1.push(list[i]);
    }
  }
}
console.log(list1);
```

Comment: Don't call `push` in the inner loop, else it will be called multiple times for the same string.

Comment: Your condition doesn't make sense. If you check every letter and push the moment you don't have a match, the only names who wouldn't be pushed is a name which only contains the letter L.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few notes to make:

1. First check whole word if it contains the letter
2. Outside that loop, push result so it gets only added once
3. Better to check it has the letter then the reverse :)

```js
var list = ['sage', 'carolina', 'everly', 'carlos', 'frankie'];
var result = [];

for(let i in list){
  var hasL = false;
  // Check every letter
  for(let j in list[i]){
    if(list[i][j].toLowerCase() === 'l') {
      hasL = true;
      break;
    }
   }
  
  // If the condition (hasL) hasn't been met, push to result
  if (!hasL) {
    result.push(list[i]);
  }

}

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. In the inner loop check if at least one element has the letter
2. If it has, add the item to the list in the outer loop

```js
const list = ['sage', 'carolina', 'everly', 'carlos', 'frankie'];
const list1 = [];

for (const str of list) {
  let hasLetter = false
  for (const char of str) {
    if (char.toLowerCase() === 'l') {
      hasLetter = true
      break
    }
  }
  if (!hasLetter) {
    list1.push(str)
  }
}
console.log(list1);
```

Shorter version below:

```js
const list = ['sage', 'carolina', 'everly', 'carlos', 'frankie'];
const list1 = list.filter(item => !/l/i.test(item))
console.log(list1)
```